# Mbp bootcamp windows 8.1 Apache don't work

Tags: windows, macos, apache-http-server, boot-camp

Computer: Apple Macbook Pro (Yosemite 10.10.3)

Bootcamp: Windows 8.1

When I install XAMPP and try to start Apache, it didn't work. The error message is below:

```
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   Problem detected!
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3676!
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Answer (score 0):

```
上午 09:14:05  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3676!
```

The above line told the main issue.

Port 443 is used by another application. Check if there are any other web server (most likely) running and configured to use SSL.